# Lost some behavior when implementing angular js custom filter function

Tags: angularjs

because I need to filter only some specific keys from an array (firstName OR lastName) I had to implement a custom filter (correct me if i'm wrong).

So I implemented a function in the corresponding controller (might create a specific filter once I get this working).
Here is the function:

```
 $scope.mama = function (baba) {
            return baba.firstName == $scope.query || baba.lastName == $scope.query;

        };
```

And here is the template:

```
Search: <input ng-model="query">

<div ng-controller="ListProscontroller" ng-init="listpros()">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in prosItems.results | filter:mama"> {{item.firstName}} </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Doing so indeed search only in firstName OR lastName as intended. But I loose several benefits:

- It becomes case sensitive
- It will match only exact matches: if first name is "Bob", "Bo" will not match when keypress "o" is released. But it will match of course "Bob" for "Bob".
  How to modify this function in order to retain default filter behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text matching is tricky. A solution that *does not take into account accented characters* (but does case-insensitive matching and substring matchng) would be:

```
$scope.mama = function (baba) {
    var firstName = baba.firstName.toUpperCase(),
        lastName = baba.lastName.toUpperCase(),
        query = $scope.query.toUpperCase();
    return firstName.indexOf(query) >= 0 || lastName.indexOf(query) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: [Angular's built-in filter](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filter.js) itself does only toLowerCase, so regarding I18N your answer should be fine. I'm surprised though that there's not a general Angular solution to this type of "search only this subset of properties" need.